# Can I refrigerate an esrog?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I recall a teshuva of R Moshe (which I can’t find and may be remembering wrong) that says that an esrog that was stored in a vacuum from last year is not kosher even though it’s perfectly yellow and beautiful.

Where I bought an esrog they also gave me a paper that said “DO NOT REFRIGERATE YOUR ESROG” (bold is theirs). This got me wondering is the issue halachik that any preservation techniques invalidate an esrog or are they simply giving what they feel to be good advice?

Comment: I would imagine that it is just advice. Many people store their hadassim and aravos in fridges to keep them fresh. An esrog doesn't need this same level of upkeep and can be stored at room temperature - https://www.lulavandetrogsets.com/assembling-your-lulav-etrog-set. Also practically, a fridge tends to be quite jam-packed over the chag and the last thing you want is for it to get squished under all the other products - https://en.etrogcenter.co.il/blog/2018/07/12/how-to-keep-your-lulav-and-etrog-set-fresh/